# VS2017 Running Post Build Event when Pressing Start

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, post-build-event

I am developing an application that uses Module injection.

My Modules are separate projects that compile to Dll's that the main application discovers at run time in a subdirectory called "Modules".

As they are not directly connected to the Main Project, when the Modules are changed the Main Project does not detect the changes, so when run, it does not build and the Post Build Event does not fire.

I build the Module which takes 2 seconds, but I have to REBUILD (a build does not fire the post build events in this situation) the main application to get the Post Build Event to fire - this takes 45 seconds.

The Post Build event simply xcopys' all the required modules to the modules directory for discovery which takes a fraction of a second. But I need the post build to fire as I require the $(ConfigurationName) etc variables. A BAT file doesn't have access to these variables.

Is there a way to get the Start Run button to fire the Post Build Event? Those 45 second intervals add up

Many thanks in advance

Lance

Comment: Project > Properties > Build Events > scroll down, "Run the post-build event", change to Always.

Comment: Unfortunately setting "Run the post-build event" to Always doesn't run the post build event when you hit start or when you build if nothing has been changed in the Main Project